# Arduino Send POST to Slack WebHook

Tags: http, arduino, http-headers

I have a Slack channel setup with a WebHook, basically I can run a POST and send a message to my channel.  All works fine when using an HTTP tool in my desktop but I am unable to send a POST from Arduino UNO + Ethernet Shield.

This is my code. Yes, I am sharing my webHookURL, no worries, this is only a test :-)

```
String PostData = "{\"text\": \"Agora Vai\"}";

Serial.println(PostData);

client.println("POST /services/TAXFFU91T/BAXFMF8BF/LPH1b60RsQpOGvur2ZNn0zpz HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: hooks.slack.com");
client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.print(PostData.length());
client.println("\n");
client.println(PostData);
client.println("");
```

**And I get a HTTP 400:**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: CloudFront
Date: Sun, 10 Jun 2018 02:30:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 556
Connection: close
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 b7a41f8635d9e8e6499fbcc9612f2ec5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: z8WMFOiFRe1nZnSzNbFdSIGriOhh0vv1TxbxFrkuZ9JUoPnssnBbrQ==

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>400 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
```

The Slack Support Team answered me this may be a mal-formed POST but I can't see where.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

it seems the JSON object format is not correct ... you may share the object which is passed to slack webhooks which would help to understand further .. Just looking at above code postData variable is not in JSON format- which causes HTTP 400 Bad Request  , you may use some other library like #include  and check ...

Checking the slack webhook using curl request gives correct output.. You may check that on slack channel

cURL Request : 
        curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
        --data '{"text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}' \
            https://hooks.slack.com/services/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

```
    https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
    10 June 2018, 03:04 UTC
    Results from running: curl --data {"text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."} --header Content-type: application/json --request POST https://hooks.slack.com/services/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 
    Response Header
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/html
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Date: Sun, 10 Jun 2018 03:04:33 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-Slack-Backend: h
    Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    X-Via: haproxy-www-19gm
    X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
    Via: 1.1 a9ced60f02a91a154a8631077a254a91.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    X-Amz-Cf-Id: XAQZ5ZSfnLCz_wOxmNbma2Q0q0GUZM_uC052kTuVglGJmGvo8AxIpg==

    Response Body
    ok
```

Comment: Hi Sanjay,  Thanks for your inputs... Yes, I saw the two tests your sent to my Channel.  I also got the same and my only problem is within Arduino code.

As far as I understood, by sending that postData String in that format would represent a Json object / string but obviusly this is not happening... Interesting that I got this from other samples around the web as well.